# Why does my custom global action not show up on my mobile device to add a new entry

Tags: custom-object, mobile, global-actions, ipad

We have set up a custom notes and call log field under the global actions. I can add a new note or call entry on the web but not on my iPad. I can see notes that have been added on the web, on my iPad.  I can edit these entries and save the edit. But I can not add a new one. Any idea as to why?  I have not been using sales force for very long but I am pretty sure I was able to before.

I believe it may be a users permissions issue but I am not sure.

Comment: Do you have the latest and greatest version of the Chatter/Salesforce1 app installed?

Comment: Also, logging out and in again should refresh the display of any global actions.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you mattandneil for the suggestion. I was having the same problem (my global actions were not appearing, even with refreshing). Solving the problem was as simple as logging out of my salesforce1 app. Once I logged back into the app the custom global action and updated layout was visible and correct.

I came across this problem while running through the Trailhead module on Salesfoce1 - the action would appear in the browser with refreshing, but not in the mobile app until I logged out and logged back in again.

Comment: Yeah same with me; was going through the Trailhead, which said all you need to do is refresh the app. That didn't work. I had to logout and log back in.

Comment: +1. Very odd - so much for the "pull down to refresh" bit.